# Foreign key error

Tags: mysql, foreign-key-relationship, mysql-error-1005

why the foreign key gives my headache?
first i created database names `colorcode` then `paper` table which works fine:

```
CREATE TABLE paper (
  paper_id int(20) NOT NULL,
  description VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  paper_color VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (paper_id, paper_color)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

then `brick` table

```
CREATE TABLE brick(
  brick_id int(20) NOT NULL,
  description varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  brick_color varchar (40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (brick_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (brick_color) REFERENCES paper(paper_color)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

which doesn't=>

`#1005 - Can't create table 'colorcode.brick' (errno: 150)`

thank you for your help

Comment: For future reference: after your query you could run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` for more info on said error. (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html for even more info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a separate key for `paper_color` and it will work:

```
CREATE TABLE paper (
    paper_id int(20) not null,
    description VARCHAR(40)not null,
    paper_color VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (paper_id, paper_color),
    KEY (paper_color)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: you rock  user4035 thanks! Should i always try to use the key to reference my foreign key to?

Comment: @LetuLater AFAIK, the index for the foreign keys can be used only for the first field in a compound primary key. That's why, I had to create a special index for the second field of your key. If you have a primary key, consisting only of 1 field, no need to create a separate index.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table paper (
  paper_id int(20) not null,
  description VARCHAR(40)not null,
  paper_color VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  primary key (paper_id, paper_color),
  INDEX(`paper_color`)
)engine=InnoDB;

create table brick (
  brick_id int(20) not null,
  description varchar(40) not null,
  brick_color varchar (40) not null,
  primary key (brick_id), 

  CONSTRAINT foreign key (`brick_color`) REFERENCES  paper(`paper_color`)
)engine=InnoDB;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/316d9

> InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any index column or group of
>   columns. However, in the referenced table, there must be an index
>   where the referenced columns are listed as the first columns in the
>   same order.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

"paper_color" has to be an index in order to reference.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you all for your prompt reply i appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

From [SQL FOREIGN KEY Constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)

> A FOREIGN KEY in one table points to a PRIMARY KEY in another table.

Now from your script, the PRIMARY KEY on table paper consists of columns paper_id, paper_color, but the foreign key referenceing it, only references paper(paper_color)

This techinically allows you to have 2 entries with

```
paper_id    paper_color
1           blue
2           blue
```

which would satisfy the primary key constraint of table paper, but not the foreign key constraint on table brick

Changing the primary key on table paper to only paper_color would work though.

```
create table paper (
paper_id int(20) not null,
description VARCHAR(40)not null,
paper_color VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
primary key ( paper_color)
)engine=InnoDB;

create table brick(
brick_id int(20) not null,
description varchar(40) not null,
brick_color varchar (40) not null,
primary key (brick_id),
foreign key (brick_color) references paper(paper_color)
)engine=InnoDB
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f2cea)

Comment: Not quite correct, it need not be a PRIMARY key, it needs to be the primary column within a key. No need to alter the PRIMARY here as it's a perfectly valid choice.